# PrimeNg dynamic MegaMenu doesn't appear

Tags: primeng, megamenu

I'm creating a MegaMenu dynamically, starting from a map:

```
this.menuItems = new Array<MegaMenuItem>();
this.map.forEach((value: Map<string, any[]>, key: string) => {
     const catArray: Array<Array<any>> = new Array<Array<any>>();
     value.forEach((inValue: any[], inKey: string) => {
         const catMenu = {
             label: inKey,
             items: inValue
         };
         catArray.push([catMenu]);
     });
     const moduleMenuItem: any = new Object();
     moduleMenuItem.label = key;
     moduleMenuItem.items = catArray;
     this.menuItems.push(moduleMenuItem);
 });
```

In HTML:

```
<p-megaMenu [model]="menuItems"></p-megaMenu>
```

The MegaMenu is correctly configured. If I test it with the example of the PrimeNg site it works fine. It seems like the object menuItems is not properly created but I can't understand where I'm wrong.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(this.menuItems)` after the block of code you posted and see in the console what `this.menuItems` actually contains when the process is done.

Comment: You can replace the three rows where `moduleMenuItem` is created with `const moduleMenuItem = { label: key, items: catArray };` like you did for `catMenu`.